# TypeError while Installing nokogiri gem on cygwin on Windows 10 -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've been trying to get ruby on rails going on Cygwin with windows 10.  At first I had some other errors that have been asked about (missing libxml2, libiconv, etc).  I think I took care of those and now get this:

```
/usr/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1189:1: note: expected ‘VALUE’ but argument   is of type ‘void *’
 rb_data_object_get(VALUE obj)
^rm -f nokogiri.so
gcc -shared -o nokogiri.so html_document.o html_element_description.o html_entit  y_lookup.o html_sax_parser_context.o html_sax_push_parser.o nokogiri.o xml_attr.  o xml_attribute_decl.o xml_cdata.o xml_comment.o xml_document.o xml_document_fra  gment.o xml_dtd.o xml_element_content.o xml_element_decl.o xml_encoding_handler.  o xml_entity_decl.o xml_entity_reference.o xml_io.o xml_libxml2_hacks.o xml_name  space.o xml_node.o xml_node_set.o xml_processing_instruction.o xml_reader.o xml_  relax_ng.o xml_sax_parser.o xml_sax_parser_context.o xml_sax_push_parser.o xml_s  chema.o xml_syntax_error.o xml_text.o xml_xpath_context.o xslt_stylesheet.o -L/h  ome/Peter/.gem/ruby/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/ports/x86_64-unknown-cygwin/libxml2/2.  9.2/lib -L/home/Peter/.gem/ruby/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/ports/x86_64-unknown-cygwi  n/libxslt/1.1.28/lib -L. -L/usr/lib -L. -fstack-protector -Wl,--export-all-symbo  ls -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base,--enable-auto-import    -lruby220 /home/Peter/.g  em/ruby/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/ports/x86_64-unknown-cygwin/libxslt/1.1.28/lib/lib  exslt.a -lm -liconv -lz /home/Peter/.gem/ruby/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/ports/x86_64  -unknown-cygwin/libxml2/2.9.2/lib/libxml2.a /home/Peter/.gem/ruby/gems/nokogiri-  1.6.7.1/ports/x86_64-unknown-cygwin/libxslt/1.1.28/lib/libxslt.a -lm -liconv -lz   /home/Peter/.gem/ruby/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/ports/x86_64-unknown-cygwin/libxml2  /2.9.2/lib/libxml2.a -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt
/usr/bin/ruby ./extconf.rb --clean --enable-static
Cleaning files only used during build.
rm -rf /home/Peter/.gem/ruby/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-    unkno  wn-cygwin/ports
rmdir -p /home/Peter/.gem/ruby/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-unk  nown-cygwin
rm -rf /home/Peter/.gem/ruby/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/ports
make "DESTDIR=" install
/usr/bin/mkdir -p . ./.gem.20160113-14536-tkk22y/nokogiri
exit > .RUBYARCHDIR.-.nokogiri.time
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 nokogiri.so ./.gem.20160113-14536-tkk22y/nokogiri

/home/Peter/bin/nokogiri
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

I've been googling quite a bit and haven't found anything that works.  I'm new to RoR and just trying to get it working.